# Do we really need a tag for an array of a specific type of object?

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request

I notice that if we take a look at the [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) [Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/arrays/synonyms) we find multiple different tags referring to arrays of specific types, such as [char-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/char-array), [character-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-arrays), [array-of-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array-of-objects). This is because a question about arrays really only needs the [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) and the relevant language tags and possibly another tag for the type if the array is of a specific type, so we apparently do not really need a tag for every array type. The only exception to this is [multidimensional-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multidimensional-array).

However I noticed there are a few missing synonyms including:

- [arrayofstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrayofstring)
- [chararray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chararray) (Which should be a synonym of [character-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-arrays) anyway, but [character-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-arrays) is a synonym of [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays))
- [array-of-dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array-of-dict)

I propose to make the above 3 tags synonyms of [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) to be consistent with the precedent that arrays of specific types do not need their own tags.

Comment: No we don't. Burn them at the stake!

Comment: Depends on who you ask. People who have an obsessive need to put 5 tags under a question probably love them. #tagsarenothashtags.

Comment: I think `array-of-objects` is OK, since there are many common questions that are specific to them (e.g. find/filter object by property value, grouping arrays of objects). My list of dupes has a folder of links for Array of Objects.